# How to use slice notation in this case?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, slice

I am solving a problem in which I am using two large matrices A and B. Matrix A is formed by ones and zeros and matrix B is formed by integers in the range `[0,...,10]`.

At some point, I have to update the components of A such that, if the component is 1 it stays at 1. If the component is 0, it can stay at 0 with probability p or change to 1 with probability 1-p. The parameters p are functions of the same component of matrix B, i.e., I have a list of probabilities such that, if I update A[i,j], then p equals the component B[i,j] of the vector probabilities

I can do the updating with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(n):
      for j in range(n):
        if A[i,j]==0:
            pass
        else:
            A[i,j]=np.random.choice([0,1],p=[probabilities[B[i,j]],1-probabilities[B[i,j]]])
```

I think that there should be a faster way to update matrix A using slice notation. Any advice?
See that this problem is equivalent to, given a vector 'a' and a matrix with positive entries 'B', obtain a matrix C in which C[i,j]=a[B[i,j]]

Comment: Are you using a library? Nothing in vanilla Python uses that syntax.

Comment: @PeterWood I guess OP is using numpy.

Comment: Yes, I have added it now. Anyway, I am looking for a way to avoid the loop, I don't mind if the solution does not use NumPy.

Comment: For a start, `mask=A==0` is a boolean array of elements you want to change.  So for example `A[mask]=2` will change all the 0s to 2.  `B[mask]` would be corresponding probabilities.  The question is whether you can create a `choice` or substitute that generates the required [0,1] for multliple `B[mask]` values.  It's not a slice or indexing issue, but a random-value generation one.

Comment: Exactly, I am looking for a way of creating something like A[A==1]=choice(B) or A[A==1]=choice(B[A==1])

Comment: I think you use of `choice` is equivalent to `(np.random.rand(n)<b[mask]),astype(int)` where `n` is the number of elements in `b[mask]` (or maybe >).   In other words a random float in the (0,1) range compared to an individual `b` value.

Comment: I don't think so. It is a choice between 0 or 1 according to a fixed probability p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The general answer

You can achieve this by generating a random value with a continuous probability, and then compare the generated value with the inverse cumulative probability function of that distribution.

### To be practical

Let's use uniform random variable `X` in the range [0, 1), then the probability that `X < a` is a. Assuming that `A` and `B` have the same shape

You can use [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this (make sure that your probabilities variable is a numpy array)

```py
A[:,:] = np.where(A == 0, np.where(np.random.rand(*A.shape) < probabilities[B], 1, 0), A);
```

If you want to avoid computing the random values for positions where A is non-zero then you have a more complex indexing.

```
A[A == 0] = np.where(np.random.rand(*A[A == 0].shape) < probabilities[B[A == 0]], 1, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not answers my question. I have a vector of probabilities with 11 entries and a matrix B with components that range from 0 to 10. You can regard it as looking for a way to obtain a matrix C in which C[i,j] = probabilities[B[i,j]]

Comment: Sorry I forgot the probabilities array and I was just computing C such that probability of C[i,j] == 1 is B[i, j]

Answer (score 0):

Make many `p` in the 0-1 range:

```
In [36]: p=np.arange(1000)/1000
```

Your `choice` use - with `sum` to get an overall statistic:

```
In [37]: sum([np.random.choice([0,1],p=[p[i],1-p[i]]) for i in range(p.shape[0])])
Out[37]: 485
```

and a statistically similar random array without the comprehension:

```
In [38]: (np.random.rand(p.shape[0])>p).astype(int).sum()
Out[38]: 496
```

You are welcome to perform other tests to verify their equivalence.

If `probabilities` is a function that takes the whole `B` or `B[mask]`, we should be able to do:

```
mask = A==0
n = mask.ravel().sum() # the number of true elements
A[mask] = (np.random.rand(n)>probabilities(B[mask])).astype(int)
```

To test this:

```
In [39]: A = np.random.randint(0,2, (4,5))
In [40]: A
Out[40]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
In [41]: mask = A==0
In [42]: A[mask]
Out[42]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
In [43]: B = np.arange(1,21).reshape(4,5)
In [44]: def foo(B):       # scale the B values to probabilites
    ...:     return B/20
    ...: 
In [45]: foo(B)
Out[45]: 
array([[0.05, 0.1 , 0.15, 0.2 , 0.25],
       [0.3 , 0.35, 0.4 , 0.45, 0.5 ],
       [0.55, 0.6 , 0.65, 0.7 , 0.75],
       [0.8 , 0.85, 0.9 , 0.95, 1.  ]])
In [46]: n = mask.ravel().sum()
In [47]: n
Out[47]: 6

In [51]: (np.random.rand(n)>foo(B[mask])).astype(int)
Out[51]: array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
In [52]: A[mask] = (np.random.rand(n)>foo(B[mask])).astype(int)
In [53]: A
Out[53]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

In [54]: foo(B[mask])
Out[54]: array([0.15, 0.2 , 0.25, 0.65, 0.7 , 1.  ])
```